# Multiple Volley Requests

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a situation I want to ask.

I have a for loop and inside the loop I make 100 HTTP requests using volley on the same server. The return response is a simple String which is the mb_strlen() of a stringify JSON object of a table (200.000 rows).

Each response returns to the main Thread via an Observer.

I make a console output for each response, but seems a little bit slow and
 prints them one by one.

```
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
      makeHTTP();
```

---

**Experiments**

- I tried to change the Volley's ThreadpoolSize to 10 and 50 but its as slow as the default's (4).
- I ran the same procedure on a browser and the delay its pretty much the same. I also saw the delay of each request.

[image]

---

**Note** that my real life application will have 100 distributed servers, each of them with different data and size, but for the experiments I have only one.

If we had those 100 separate servers would be any difference in speed?